# How to implement SASL/EXTERNAL for OpenLDAP client over IPC on Golang?

Tags: go, external, openldap, sasl

I'm currently trying to implement `SASL/EXTERNAL` auth for OpenLDAP client written in Golang.

By other words, I want to load the following data:

```
ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:// -s base -b 'olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config' olcSyncRepl
```

I'm using https://github.com/go-ldap/ldap library. Unfortunately, the library supports simple authentication only. I'm happy to implement `SASL/EXTERNAL` but I could not recognize how the protocol works? For example, there is https://ldap.com/ldapv3-wire-protocol-reference-bind/ `CRAM-MD5` authentication process.

I want to get the same explanation for `SASL/EXTERNAL`.

I connected to the unix socket (`ldapi://`) successfully. But I don't understand what kind of commands need to send programmatically to complete authentication.

Comment: It's a bit dense, but the RFC has the SASL spec & message format: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4511. Cross referencing that with the go-ldap package source may get you further along.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

First of all, you need to connect to the unix socket. Usually, the socket locates on `/var/run/slapd/ldapi` path.

Then you need to make a simple bind with two changes:

1. username should be empty
2. need specify that you want to use `sasl` authentication

```golang
pkt := ber.Encode(ber.ClassApplication, ber.TypeConstructed, ApplicationBindRequest, nil, "Bind Request")
pkt.AppendChild(ber.NewInteger(ber.ClassUniversal, ber.TypePrimitive, ber.TagInteger, 3, "Version"))
pkt.AppendChild(ber.NewString(ber.ClassUniversal, ber.TypePrimitive, ber.TagOctetString, "", "User Name"))

saslAuth := ber.Encode(ber.ClassContext, ber.TypeConstructed, 3, "", "authentication")
saslAuth.AppendChild(ber.NewString(ber.ClassUniversal, ber.TypePrimitive, ber.TagOctetString, "EXTERNAL", "SASL Mech"))
saslAuth.AppendChild(ber.NewString(ber.ClassUniversal, ber.TypePrimitive, ber.TagOctetString, "", "SASL Cred"))

pkt.AppendChild(saslAuth)
```

This is the PR https://github.com/go-ldap/ldap/pull/232.